# Does the lithosphere have a resonant frequency?

Tags: waves, material-science, earth, resonance

In meteorological sciences, there is an important concept known as the Schumann resonance, which are the integer values of electromagnetic resonance between the surface and ionosphere. The values change as the distance between these two isn't constant.

With that in mind, is there a resonance value for the lithosphere? Just as in the Schumann resonance, there is a range of distances between the crust and the asthenosphere; or other boundaries, such as the Moho layer.
Are there phenomena that display themselves like this in the world?

Comment: [Seismic waves: Normal modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismic_wave#Normal_modes)

Comment: Read the article but it does not seem to describe the values they can take. I am not aware of Evamentality’s knowledge level of geophysics, but it was not a cut dry answer.